# PHP error: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: php, wordpress, git

I've got a strange bug- I am working on a site storing in WP engine, and I'm working with git. Every time I git push to the site, after the push is finish, the inner page's of the site can't be accessed due to 500 internal server error. This problem is fixed easly by just saving the permalinks settings page (without change anything). When the site wasn't live, that wasn't so much of a big deal. However now as the site live I must solve this, but I can't find the bug. 
I already deactivate all the plugins in the staging, it didn't help. The error logs says:
`AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://the-site.com`

Any idea what can cause this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I manage to solve this by change `.htaccess` file from this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project-name/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /project-name/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

To this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same error, I can not solve it, the blank page appears. If he found that at least me of database error included the next code.

```
# mod_rewrite set:

Options +Includes

RewriteEngine on

# Administration
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/+)admin/(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/admin/index.php [L,QSA]

# Rewrite orther
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/+)index.php(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/+)syscmd.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

# If Rewriting Failure, Show error message (Internal backup)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/+)index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/+)syscmd.php$
RewriteRule (.*) \1 [F]
```

En el htcaccess  :(:(